# Eval где используется?

Tags: javascript, eval

Зачем нужно использовать `eval` в JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод для выполнения произвольного кода, может использовать переменные и свойства существующих объектов.

```
var str = "if (a) { 1 + 1 } else { 2 + 2 }";
var a = true;
var b = eval(str);
alert("b равно : " + b); // b равно : 2

// теперь поменяем "a"

a = false;
b = eval(str);
alert("b равно : " + b) // b равно : 4
```

Выполнение кода в eval может быть небезопасно. При таком выполнении затруднена отладка.

Ответ на вопрос же: не нужно его использовать.

`eval`:

1. Требует компиляции, поэтому медленный.
2. Вредоносный скрипт может найти доступ к `eval` как аргумент.
3. Не красив =\
4. Наследует контекст выполнения, и связан с областью, в которой его вызывает.

**Пример использования**: выполнения кода полученного с помощью `XMLHttpRequest`/ `Ajax`. У вас есть сервер и ваша страничка, вы не хотите обновлять страницу постоянно. Отправляете `Ajax` запрос к серверу, он возвращает код, выполняете, используя `eval`. Если взять стааарый пример с `XMLHttpRequest`, то как-то так:

```
function evalRequest(url) {
     var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
               eval(xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
     xmlhttp.send(null);
 }
```

Comment: А зачем его тогда вообще не убирают к чёрту?

Comment: @LEQADA иногда он очень полезен. Для дебага например используется часто.

Comment: Не могли бы в ответе показать пример случая, когда он действительно к месту?

Comment: @LEQADA я лично предпочитаю его не использовать. Но, например, если вам нужно динамически генерировать код, то eval само то.

Comment: @LEQADA как пример, получать Ajax'ом какой-то JS код с сервера и выполнять его, не обновляя страницы

Comment: Да, вот JSON тоже в голову пришёл только что. Спасибо.